# Optimize a subquery searching for records in another table based on dates not in the past 360 days

Tags: mysql, sql

Problem:
Find people whose birthdays are tomorrow (table a), who havent got a record with an issue date set in the past 360 days from (table b)

```
Table a
ID, DOB

Table b
ID, PID, Issued
```

I've got a query but it's pretty slow, not sure if a join would be quicker - any help appreciated..

```
SELECT a.ID, a.DOB FROM a
WHERE MONTH(a.DOB)=MONTH(now()) # match month
AND DAYOFMONTH(a.DOB)=DAYOFMONTH(now()+ INTERVAL 1 DAY) # match day of month
AND (
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM b 
 WHERE b.PID = a.ID 
 AND b.Issued < DATE_SUB(SYSDATE(), INTERVAL 360 DAY) 
) < 1 # hacky subquery to find not issued in past 360 days
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT      *
FROM        A
LEFT JOIN   B
        ON  A.Id = B.PID AND B.Issued >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 360 DAY)
WHERE       B.ID IS NULL AND
            DATE_ADD(A.DOB, INTERVAL YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(A.DOB) YEAR) = 
            DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: To allow using a possible index on `A.DOB`: `… WHERE B.ID IS NULL AND A.DOB = DATE_SUB(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), INTERVAL YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(A.DOB) YEAR)`.

Comment: @AndriyM, I'm not sure if an index will be used on that DOB column, as an expression needs to be execute on every row to determine if it's an desired record. But you suggestion make this query simpler, thanks

Comment: You probably mean that `A.DOB` also takes part in calculation (`YEAR(A.DOB)`). At least, that's what I definitely missed. Maybe, it should be a test of `A.DOB` against a set of tomorrow's dates for all the years starting from a certain pre-determined minimum to the current one (collected with the help of a numbers table, probably). But I'm not sure, and that would complicate the resulting query anyway.